# How to Get the Value of a label control inside the Template of a Gridview column using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

i am having a gridView. i need to throw a popup when User clicks a link button  inside the gridview in the 2nd column. The 6th column of a gridview is having comma - seperated Ids.

All i need to do is genrate a popup when user clicks the link button.Popup will Show the listview or gridview which will display these comma seperated Ids  .... HELP!

Comment: What gridView are you talking about? Can you please post the code that you tried? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net there is the "OnClientClick" attribute on the Linkbutton, which specifies client side script to run when the click event is raised bind you function with it.

And if ur problem not resolved then elaborate your problem completeley.

like :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMyButton" runat="Server" OnClientClick="ButtonClick()" />
<script>
var ButtonClick = function () {
  alert ('fire');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank u So much for your reply. i have managed to get the Ids(comma seperated)..from the column. but my problem starts when i need to populate these values (split by ,) to a gridview.. i want to do and my need is to do all this work through Jquery....

Comment: i would like to add the further thing is the 6th column i mentioned is set to visible = "FALSE"